# Symfony 3 Attempted to load class "LessonRepository" from namespace "DrumLessonBookingApp\DrumLessonBookingBundle\Repository"

Tags: php, symfony, frameworks, doctrine

When trying to get the default repository class for my entity Lesson I keep getting the following error:

> Attempted to load class "LessonRepository" from namespace "DrumLessonBookingApp\DrumLessonBookingBundle\Repository".
>   Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

I use the exact same method as a User entity which works perfectly fine.

The code for my controller is:

```
namespace DrumLessonBookingApp\DrumLessonBookingBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request; 
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response; 
use DrumLessonBookingApp\DrumLessonBookingBundle\Entity\User; 
use DrumLessonBookingApp\DrumLessonBookingBundle\Entity\Lesson; 
use DrumLessonBookingApp\DrumLessonBookingBundle\Repository;


class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function displayAction()
    {
        return $this->render('DrumLessonBookingAppDrumLessonBookingBundle:Default:login.html.twig'); 
    }

    public function processloginAction(Request $request)
    {
        $doctrine = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); 
        $email = $request->get('email'); 
        $pwd = $request->get('pwd'); 


        $user = $doctrine->getRepository('DrumLessonBookingAppDrumLessonBookingBundle:User')->findOneBy(array('email' => $email,'password' => $pwd));


        if($user->getAdministrator() == 1)
        {
            $session = $this->get('session'); 
            $session->set('loggedin', true);

            $lessons = $doctrine->getRepository('DrumLessonBookingAppDrumLessonBookingBundle:Lesson')->findAll(); 


            return $this->render('DrumLessonBookingAppDrumLessonBookingBundle:Default:dashboard.html.twig', array("lessons" => $lessons));   
        }
        else {
            return new Response('doctrine not working'); 
        }
    }
}
```

I am also having difficulty to generate a custom Respository class using doctrine so tried creating one myself for the User entity but symfny doesn't pick it up or recognise the custom method. See below:

```
namespace DrumLessonBookingApp\DrumLessonBookingBundle\Repository; 
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository; 
use DrumLessonBookingApp\DrumLessonBookingBundle\Entity\User; 

class UserRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function loginUser($email, $password)
    {
        $entityM = $this->getEntityManager(); 
        $dql = $entityM->createQuery(
            'SELECT u FROM DrumLessonBookingAppDrumLessonBookingBundle:User u
                WHERE u.email = :email 
                AND WHERE u.password = :pwd');

        $dql->setParameter('email', $email); 
        $dql->setParameter('pwd', $password); 

        $user = $query->getResult(); 
        return $user; 
    }
}
```

I have searched similar questions but cannot find a solution, someone please help!

My Lesson Entity

```
namespace DrumLessonBookingApp\DrumLessonBookingBundle\Entity; 
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM; 

/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="lessons")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="DrumLessonBookingApp\DrumLessonBookingBundle\Repository\LessonRepository")
 * */
   class Lesson {

   /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * */
private $id; 

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date")
 * */
private $date; 

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="time")
 * */
private $time; 

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="lessons")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * */
private $user; 

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set date
 *
 * @param \DateTime $date
 *
 * @return Lesson
 */
public function setDate($date)
{
    $this->date = $date;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get date
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getDate()
{
    return $this->date;
}

/**
 * Set time
 *
 * @param \DateTime $time
 *
 * @return Lesson
 */
public function setTime($time)
{
    $this->time = $time;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get time
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getTime()
{
    return $this->time;
}


/**
 * Set User
 * 
 * @param object
 * @return Lesson
 * */
public function setUser(User $user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
    return $this;  
}

   /**
 * Set User
 * 
 * 
 * @return User
 * */
public function getUser($user)
{
    return $this->user;   
}

}
```

There is nothing in my custom Lesson Repository but surely it should still find the methods such as findAll() etc from the entityRepository it extends

Comment: could you plase show the Entity: Lesson?

Comment: and your `LessonRepository`..

Comment: I have edited the question to inclue the lesson entity. Thanks for taking the time to help

Answer (score 0):

seems you have multiple questions  for one answer

you need to reference the repositoryClass it in your Entity-class :

```
/**
 * USER
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="DrumLessonBookingApp\DrumLessonBookingBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User
{
```

i guess you missing the same  at your Lesson Entity.
You dont have to add a "use" statement then

Comment: I already have in both entities, thats why I can't understand why they are not working.

Comment: here is the start of my user entity class `<?php

namespace DrumLessonBookingApp\DrumLessonBookingBundle\Entity; 

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;  

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="Users")
 * */

/*
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="DrumLessonBookingApp\DrumLessonBookingBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 * */
Class User {

 `